# How to fix MS Graph message body search?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using graph explorer to execute the following message search by subject works as expected:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search=%22subject%3Agoogle.com%3A443%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Da%2Btest*%22
```

However, this message search by body fails.  The only difference between this and the previous search is that subject is replaced with body:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search=%22body%3Agoogle.com%3A443%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Da%2Btest*%22
```

The error that I receive for the second search is "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., Too few pops in query tree".

This search used to work.  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a 500 error - you won't make this work. I'll report this as an error. The error appears to be with the second colon in the search string.

`$search="body:google.com:443/search?q=a+test*"` - this 500s

`$search="body:google.com443/search?q=a+test*"` - this 200s

**Conjecture**

I suspect that the search feature now supports multiple fields as the following query works as expected:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="body:Minerva subject:pilot"`

This would break your query as it appears that the colon is only considered for specifying the field to search on.

**Potential workaround**

You could break your query string into multiple parts like this:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="body:google.com AND body:443/search?q=a+test*"`

It is not sufficient but may work for your scenario.

Comment: Thank you @Michael.  When do you think there will be a fix for this?  We are depending on this as part of a product release.

Comment: @user10771554 I haven't heard back yet on the state of this issue. I can't guess on if/when a fix would be made.

Comment: @MichaelMainer Any updates on this? We badly need the fix for one of our integrations that rely on this API.

Comment: @viv, I don't have any updates on this. Are you experiencing the same behavior?

Comment: @MichaelMainer. We have tested this in graph explorer and we are getting the same results as before.